# HandleLongPressGesture is only called once when adding a subview

Tags: ios, ipad, mkmapview, uigesturerecognizer

I am using the handleLongPressGesture to add an annotation and to create a textfield next my MapView.
My problem is, that the function is only called once when I am inserting a subview:
**`[self createTextfieldForPin:myString :x :y];`**

Does anybody know, why?
Without that function the handleLongPressGesture-function is called every time, when I am doing a lond press...

Here is my complete code:

```
-(void)handleLongPressGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer*)sender
{
    // This is important if you only want to receive one tap and hold event
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        //[self.mapView removeGestureRecognizer:sender];

 //       [self.mapView removeAnnotations:[self.mapView annotations]];
    }
    else
    {

        // Here we get the CGPoint for the touch and convert it to latitude and longitude coordinates to display on the map
        CGPoint point = [sender locationInView:self.mapView];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D locCoord = [self.mapView convertPoint:point toCoordinateFromView:self.mapView];
        // Then all you have to do is create the annotation and add it to the map
        UserAnnotation *dropPin = [[UserAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:locCoord];
        [self.mapView addAnnotation:dropPin];

        //create NSString from coordinate
        NSNumberFormatter *fmt = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        [fmt setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
        NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@ / %@",[fmt stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:locCoord.latitude]],[fmt stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:locCoord.longitude]]];

      [self createTextfieldForPin:myString :x :y];
    }
}
```

**Edit

```
-(void)createTextfieldForPin:(NSString *)coordinates: (CGFloat) _x: (CGFloat) _y
{
    self.label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 100.0, 21.0)];
    self.label.text = coord;
    y = y + 25.0;
    self.textfield = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,163,31)];
    self.textfield.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    [self.view addSubview:self.label];
    [self.view addSubview:self.textfield];
```

}

**EDIT

Everytime when i am adding a pin I want also to create a label (for the coordinates) and a textfield to add a city or sth else.
Like on the pic. But I can call the handleLongPressGesture only one time when the createTextfieldForPin is inside that function.. and I don't know why

[image]

Comment: What does createTextfieldForPin do exactly?  Can you show that code?

Comment: The createTextfieldForPin method creates a new label and textfield (at new positions) each time a pin is added.  Can you explain in more detail what you're trying to achieve and what's happening instead?